# Trouble with Pandas vectorization

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization

I am trying to run a function across an entire pandas series and create a new series of values. My issue is that every row of the new series is the same exact combination of every result.

```
def create_meta_names(x):
    name=str(x).upper()
    for clean in NameCleaner:
        name=name.replace(clean ,'')            
    for expand in NamesExpander:
        name = name.replace(expand, NamesExpander[expand])
    tmp = re.compile(r"\b[a-zA-Z]\b")
    name =  re.sub(tmp, "", name)
    name = (normalize_unicode_to_ascii(name)).strip()
    tp = tuple(name.split(" "))
    concat_name = generate_normalized_name(tp)
    metaphone_tuple = doublemetaphone(concat_name)
    return metaphone_tuple[0]

table['Metas'] = create_meta_names(table['Name'])
```

This function takes someone's name and standardizes it to a metaphone code that can be used to match similar names based on phonetic spelling. Again, the problem is that my reselt is a combination of every result copied to every row. I don't know why this is happening.

```
0         P...TNK...TPFN...FNK...FX...RS...N...KJ...
1         P...TNK...TPFN...FNK...FX...RS...N...KJ...
2         P...TNK...TPFN...FNK...FX...RS...N...KJ...
3         P...TNK...TPFN...FNK...FX...RS...N...KJ...
4         P...TNK...TPFN...FNK...FX...RS...N...KJ...
                                ...                        
438130    P...TNK...TPFN...FNK...FX...RS...N...KJ...
438131    P...TNK...TPFN...FNK...FX...RS...N...KJ...
438132    P...TNK...TPFN...FNK...FX...RS...N...KJ...
438133    P...TNK...TPFN...FNK...FX...RS...N...KJ...
438134    P...TNK...TPFN...FNK...FX...RS...N...KJ...
```

Ideally, I am trying to get 1 record per row. i.e.

```
'Vance Harris' >>> 'HRSFNS'
```

Comment: You can do a lot of the stuff in the function vectorised. For example `table['Metas'].str.upper()` does the `upper` (see [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.upper.html)), same for `replace`, I think for `sub` you can also use `...str.replace(...)`. But since it is unclear what functions do that you are using it's hard to say if they can replaced too.

Answer (score 0):

```py
table['Metas'] = table['Name'].apply(create_meta_names)
```

will work row-by-row.

Comment: So ideally i am trying to avoid using .apply as it is much slower. I already have a lot of my functionality running .apply and I am trying to improve them.

Comment: Currently you are passing the full pandas series into your function and the first thing you do is ```str(x)``` which basically makes a huge string of the whole series at once. Try print that out. You need to use ```.apply()``` or make a loop inside your function to execute your code row by row

Comment: That makes sense to me. But I am referencing this tutorial https://engineering.upside.com/a-beginners-guide-to-optimizing-pandas-code-for-speed-c09ef2c6a4d6. I have constructed my vectorization approach similar to them, but can't figure out why its working for them and not for me. Excuse my misunderstandings, but I thought vectorizing in this manner would apply the same function to every row at once. Not having to iterate row by row, thus slowing the process down by a lot.

Comment: Their fastest code reads
```
df['distance'] = haversine(40.671, -73.985, df['latitude'].values, df['longitude'].values)
```

Comment: ```str(x)``` just won't work element-wise as it would if you were to do ```sin(x)``` where x is a numpy array.